# getdate() query via resultset throwing no current row exception

Tags: java, sql-server, resultset, jtds

I have a problem here, what i wanna do is getting current date and a column from a table. Here is my code so far :

```
s = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
rset = s.executeQuery("select getdate() as date, tglpengiriman from orders");
java.sql.Date date = rset.getDate("date");
java.sql.Date tglkirim = rset.getDate("tglpengiriman");
```

And throwing exception "no current row in ResultSet" in line 3 of my code above.
What's wrong with my code? Missunderstanding usage of ResultSet, maybe?

Thanks for any answer...

EDIT:
answered. Please see post from @Christopher below. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call ResultSet.next before you call any of the ResultSet.get* methods. Take a look at the documentation for Statement, ResultSet, etc. Also be sure to close all your resources in a 'finally' block.

Comment: oh yes sorry, my mistake.. I forget to call resultset.next. This always happened. Poor me. Thanks @christopher

Answer (score 0):

You need to call 
`rset.next()` before getting the data from the result set.  It is also wise to check that `rset.next()` returned true.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate Your data of result set Like this

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
java.sql.Date date = rset.getDate("date");
java.sql.Date tglkirim = rset.getDate("tglpengiriman"); 
}
```

because initial position of result set is always before first record i.e at beginning of first record , this resultSet.next() makes your result set to point to the first record.